# MySql: hard match on same table

Tags: mysql, count, match

I have a table containing products from shop's orders

```
+----------------------------+
| orders_id | products_model |
+----------------------------+
|   1000    | aa0000001      |
|   1000    | bb0000002      |
|   1000    | cc0000001      |
|   1001    | aa0000001      |
|   1002    | bb0000001      |
|   1003    | cc0000001      |
|   1004    | bb0000001      |
|   1004    | aa0000001      |
+----------------------------+
```

Every order can have, of course, one or more items

I need a list of only orders containing only items with code starting with aa or bb (or both)
I don't want to list orders containing items with code starting with evey other code type.

Example:

```
+-----------+
| orders_id |
+-----------+
|   1001    |         
|   1002    | 
|   1004    |
+-----------+
```

Order 1000 has to be excluded because it has a 'cc' item beside 'aa' and 'bb' ones
Order 1003 has to be excluded because it has a 'cc' item

I started experimenting to compare count of matching records and count of all records for every order.....but I soon had to stop...I'm a sql newbie so I lost myself in a jungle of nested queries :)

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Think this may be what you require

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders_id FROM orders ord
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Orders_Id
    FROM orders
    WHERE products_model  LIKE 'cc%' OR products_model LIKE 'dd%') ccDdItems
ON ccDdItems.Orders_id = ord.Orders_id
WHERE ccDdItems.Orders_Id IS NULL
```

As LittleBobbyTables points out, if you also have 'ee', 'ff' etc, you may want to replace the inner query with  `NOT LIKE 'aa%' AND NOT LIKE 'bb%'`

Comment: While that works, and the OP didn't specify it anything other than `aa`, `bb` and `cc`, this will start to bog down if they have to exclude `ee`, `ff`, etc. from the list.

Comment: True.  Updated with a comment

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o1.orders_id) orders_id
FROM orders o1
LEFT JOIN orders o2
  ON o1.orders_id = o2.orders_id
 AND o2.products_model NOT LIKE 'aa%' 
 AND o2.products_model NOT LIKE 'bb%'
WHERE o2.orders_id IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0d7/7).

...or a `NOT IN`...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(orders_id) orders_id
FROM orders
WHERE orders_id NOT IN
  ( SELECT orders_id FROM orders 
    WHERE products_model NOT LIKE 'aa%' 
      AND products_model NOT LIKE 'bb%')
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0d7/9).

...or `NOT EXISTS`...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(orders_id) oid
FROM orders
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( SELECT 0 FROM orders o2 
    WHERE orders.orders_id = o2.orders_id 
      AND o2.products_model NOT LIKE 'aa%' 
      AND o2.products_model NOT LIKE 'bb%')
```

[Yet another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0d7/13).

Answer (score 0):

There's a way with a `HAVING` clause, but it's possibly a bit too tricky for its own good:

```
SELECT
    orders_id
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY orders_id
  HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(products_model LIKE 'aa%' OR
                      products_model LIKE 'bb%',
                      TRUE)) = 0;
```

Part of the trick is knowing that `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of rows for which the `<expression>` returns a non-`NULL` result. The other part is using `NULLIF(<test>, TRUE)` to return `NULL` for any row where the `<test>` is `TRUE`.

In this case, we effectively ask for `orders_id` values for orders which have zero entries that don't match the `products_model LIKE ...` test.

Here's [a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42843/1) you can use to play around with it.

The potential payoff for this version over the ones offered by Joachim Isaksson is that, without any subqueries or joins, the query plan is simpler, and so the performance is potentially better. However, as for all performance arguments, YMMV and you should measure with realistic data before factoring it in. Any performance gain may not be worth the maintenance cost of the tricky-ness.